# Bad internet access after defining fix ethernet IP-address

Tags: networking, wireless, ip, gateway, ip-address

I have assigned a fix IP address to my ethernet connection for some project. Since then, my Wifi is extremely slow and sometimes I can't even access webpages. As I'm not specialist into this, so I might have changed something wrong but I can't figure out what. I have the following setup: `ubuntu@master:~$ ifconfig`:

```
wlp65s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.160  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2001:171b:2269:80:31b7:25ec:c36e:6823  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:1da1:a7e1:5729:1050  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::d6c7:1b3d:1e0b:5c2e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:c847:d06f:b111:5c5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2001:171b:2269:80:1da1:a7e1:5729:1050  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2001:171b:2269:80:7863:65c7:2f72:50e5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 84:1b:77:a6:de:16  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 246113  bytes 216699304 (216.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 134602  bytes 32519445 (32.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp4s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::b62e:99ff:fe31:55a0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b4:2e:99:31:55:a0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 419407  bytes 369641096 (369.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1018506  bytes 1287911312 (1.2 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xd9500000-d951ffff
```

where `wlp65s0` is my wlan internet connection which was working ok before I made some changes. `enp4s0` is my ethernet connection.I also have `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#this has been added:
    allow-hotplug enp4s0
    iface enp4s0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.1
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

Then: `sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd #before, this was NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
      addresses: [192.168.1.1/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
          search: [255.255.255.0]
          addresses: [1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1, 192.168.1.1]
```

ls `-al /etc/netplan`:

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 28 18:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 146 root root 12288 Apr 28 18:16 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   506 Apr 28 17:53 01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

dkms status

```
nvidia, 460.73.01, 5.4.0-72-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Could you please point me out where you see any inconsistency ? Please tell me if anything is missing or unclear. Any hint or help would be highly appreciated. I have Wifi Card Aorus GC-WBAX200 and I am running on Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Wouldn't be better to assign the IP at the router?

Comment: Is this a Desktop or Server installation? If you wish to use Netplan, then your additions to /etc/network/interfaces should be removed. Isn't 192.168.1.1 the address or your router... if so, you can't use it. Why isn't wlp65s0 defined in your .yaml? Edit your question and show me `dkms status`. Show me `ls -al /etc/netplan`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ubuntu Desktop...

Your /etc/network/interfaces should be:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Your /etc/netplan/01-cloud-init.yaml should be:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Then use the NetworkManager GUI to set static addresses (if desired):

Note: The static address cannot be the address of your router (192.168.1.1).

[image]